# Got a "401 - Unauthorized" when trying my WCF Data service on IIS

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis, wcf-data-services

I developed a WCF Data Service, which runs fine, I can do every operation I want through.

I developed a small c# client which tests all functions: adding, removing, modifying, retrieving data.

Everything works fine on my visual studio server, but once I'm on the IIS Server:

- I can add/retrieve data
- I cannot edit data

When I try to edit data I get this error:

> System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceRequestException was unhandled
>   Message=Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de cette
>   requête.
>   Source=System.Data.Services.Client
>   StackTrace:
>   à System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.SaveResult.HandleBatchResponse()
>   à System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.SaveResult.EndRequest()
>   à System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.SaveChanges(SaveChangesOptions
>   options)
>   à System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.SaveChanges()
>   à WSTester.Program.ModifySomeThings(Entities entities) dans
>   D:\Workspace\10067.GfK
>   Telecontrol.TOM\Release\V3.1\WSTester\Program.cs:ligne 90
>   à WSTester.Program.Main(String[] args) dans
>   D:\Workspace\10067.GfK
>   Telecontrol.TOM\Release\V3.1\WSTester\Program.cs:ligne 23
>   à System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly
>   assembly, String[] args)
>   à System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>   à Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>   à System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object
>   state)
>   à System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   ignoreSyncCtx)
>   à System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>   à System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
>   InnerException:
>   System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceClientException
>   Message=
>   Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
>   
>   
>       
>       401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid
>   credentials.
>
> .content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}
>       -->
>
> ## Server Error
>
> ### 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid
>   credentials.
>
> #### You do not have permission to view this directory or page
>   using the credentials that you supplied.
>
> Source=System.Data.Services.Client
>   StatusCode=401
>   StackTrace:
>   à System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.SaveResult.d__1e.MoveNext()
>   InnerException:

Which is strange, because I've all rights in my WCF Data service(and it works with visual studio), and I'm in anonymous mode in IIS, so I should have all rights to runs this query. IIS_USR has FULL CONTROL on the web folder, so I really don't see what can be the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the impersonation features of the app pool to user that has permissions. I have had many problems in the past using the default `AppPoolIdentity` features of IIS 7 and generally assign it to either a user setup for this very purpose or set it to use networkservice.

It is most likely that the pool doesn't have the proper permissions to execute properly.

Comment: i should also note if you are hosting several apps on the same server you should give them different user impersonations so they cannot access each other in the event the server is hacked which was the intention of the app pool identity i have just had many problems getting the permissions set up properly with apppoolidentity

Answer (score 6):

I just fixed mine by giving "full control" to the "IUSR" account for the WCF folder.  That's all I did and it worked.

Comment: I just added Write permissions to that "IUSR" user and it fixed the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I made it run with a custom user and now it works, so if you have this problem, you can try the following on your IIS Server:

1. Create a windows user;
2. Give it read/write/modify/execute/... rights on your WCF data service folder;
3. Create a new app pool with .NET 4, integrated mode, and this user;
4. On the authentication of the website, enable only the anonymous mode, and set the user to "Application Pool identity".