# How to call WCF windows auth protected service from Jquery in MS Dynamics CRM

Tags: jquery, wcf, iis, dynamics-crm, windows-authentication

I have a WCF service hosted in IIS. Authentication mode is set to Windows in web.config and IIS level.

I have a user interface from which the service gets called from jQuery ajax method.

Here is how I am calling service from jQuery.

```js
$.ajax({
            async: true,
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            crossDomain: true,
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            },
            data: <<Data>>,
            url: <<Service url>>,
            success: function (data) {
                OnFetchSuccess(<<Some Params>>);
            },
            error: function () { }
        });
```

This call fails with error code 401 (Unauthorized).

Can someone please help in this issue?

Comment: try with  xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    }, in your ajax call . If its doesn't work then you may need to add authorization headers in your request

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Got a "401 - Unauthorized" when trying my WCF Data service on IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7103079/got-a-401-unauthorized-when-trying-my-wcf-data-service-on-iis)

Comment: same as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2205038/401-unauthorized-error-wcf-security-binding

Comment: Above 2 threads are calling service from code behind. I am facing issue when it is called from jQuery. From c# it works.